# Cannot convert milliseconds to date if value is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript

I don't know why I can't convert my timestamp in milliseconds to Date if the value in ms is stored in a variable, while if i type the value directly in the Date object constructor it works without any problem.

CODE:

```js
var milliseconds = data[item].time;
var date = new Date(milliseconds);
```

Error: Invalid Date
while `var date = new Date(1513033025024); //THE SAME VALUE OF "milliseconds" above` works

Comment: Are you sure the 'time' gives you milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure, I've also done an `alert(milliseconds)` and the output is correct

Comment: Are you certain that `milliseconds` contains the value you expect at the time you're using it?  Have you tried adding a `console.log(milliseconds)` between those 2 lines?

Comment: What's `data`? I posted your code to a snippet but as you can see, your example is incomplete.

Comment: What is the data type of `milliseconds`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `milliseconds` will only deal with numeric values and it is a string, you could try this:

```
var milliseconds = data[item].time;
var date = new Date(+milliseconds);
```

The `+` will convert `miliiseconds` if string in number, if `milliseconds` is number, then nothing happens.

Comment: YES, that worked, if you could explain that better I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `milliseconds` is most likely a string. Try with

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(milliseconds, 10));
```